# How install laravel-elixir-livereload on laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir, gulp-livereload

I installed step by step from https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-livereload
but it doesn't work.

```
npm install --save-dev laravel-elixir-livereload
```

Next, I added it to my Elixir-enhanced Gulpfile, like:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-livereload');
elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.livereload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`livereload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-livereload) needs its own script to work with. According to the `laravel-elixir-livereload` documentation, you must inject `livereload` script to your  blade templates. You can inject the script in your blade templates as follows:

**Check if debugging is true**

```
@if ( Config::get('app.debug') )
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')
  </script> 
@endif
```

**Insert manually**(For example, place the script end of `body` tag or `head` tag)

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: what is it and content :
livereload.js